# Dinamically add/remove element in bootstrap grid using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm writing a picture gallery using a bootstrap grid to display all images.
The user can upload a new image using a modal form...and can remove each displaied picture using a button in each grid element.

Below the jquery function to draw the gallery into a div with popup-gallery class

```
function getPictures(id) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'GET',
        url: `${controller_url}/collect_pictures/${id}`,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(".loader").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    }).done(function(data){ 
        $(".loader").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $('.pictures-buttons').show();
        $( ".popup-gallery" ).empty();
        if(data.pictures.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0, j = data.pictures.length; i < j; i++){
                if(i==0 || i%4 == 0)
                {
                    var appendEl = $("<div class='row'></div>").appendTo(".popup-gallery");
                }
                $(`
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <a href="${data.picture_path}${data.pictures[i].image}" data-source="">
                                <div class="img-responsive">
                                    <img src="${data.picture_path}${data.pictures[i].image}" alt="" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Filename: ${data.pictures[i].image}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Uploaded: ${data.pictures[i].uploadtime}</p>
                                <p class="card-text">File data: ${data.pictures[i].sizes} / ${data.pictures[i].filesize}</p>
                                <div class="button-list" data-id="${data.pictures[i].imgid}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light picture-button"><i class="mdi mdi-spotlight-beam mr-1"></i> Details</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect waves-light picture-button">Remove <i class="mdi mdi-trash-can ml-1"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end col -->
                `).appendTo(appendEl);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $( ".alert" ).html( "No pictures for the selected registration." );
        }
    });
}
```

So far I can succesfully delete each picture element using the code below:

```
$("body").on("click",".picture-button",function(e){
    var id = $(this).parents('div').data('id');
    if(id != null) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).find("i").hasClass("mdi-spotlight-beam")) {
            viewPicture(id);
        }
        if($(this).find("i").hasClass("mdi-trash-can")) {
            removePicture(id);
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide({
                duration:500
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But I got in trouble since I'd like to reord the grid after an element has been removed....right now, if I remove the first image, that space stay empty.
Any hint to fix the issue?

Same to add dinamically a new element after the user upload a new image.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you write the pics to the html and there you just hide them. So you have to add an array to which you direct the ajax response, then you have the possibility to add/remove pics and afterwards reorder the view.

Functions (pseudo code) you'll need

```
// modify the items array (push/remove/edit)
 myGallery.items.push({
      src: "some-image.jpg"
  });

 // call update method to refresh counters (if required)
 myGallery.updateItemHTML();
```